# Difference between 受{う}ける and もらう

Tags: grammar, usage, meaning

What is the difference between 受{う}ける and もらう? Both translates as "receive"..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- もらう - the most common use is when you express gratitude by "receiving" someone's action - 一緒に行ってもらう。 One more use is when you receive something from someone, as mentioned in the comment below: 友達からプレゼントをもらう。
- 受ける (うける) - when you receive something, but not personally from someone, such as e-mail.
- 得る (うる) - when you receive something non-material. Such as approval.

Comment: `もらう` can be used with things too: `友達からプレゼントをもらった`.

Comment: of course. Should have mentioned it.